# Расположение объектов в JPanel

Tags: java

Имеется такой код на Java:

```
package Game;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class avt extends JPanel{

    Dimension sizeWindow = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Image bg_launch = new ImageIcon("images/style/launch.jpg").getImage();

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawImage(bg_launch, 0, 0,null);
    }

    JTextField login = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField password = new JTextField(10);
    JButton submit = new JButton("Войти");  
}
```

В главном классе, я класс avt вызываю как панель - это понятно.

**Вопрос:**

Как задать размещение данным объектам:

```
JTextField login = new JTextField(10);
JTextField password = new JTextField(10);
JButton submit = new JButton("Войти");
```

Методом `setBounds()` в классе `avt`

*Спасибо*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно подсказали, что необходимо разобраться со слоями.
НО т.к. в вопросе явно указано то, что надо юзать setBounds, то применяется абсолютное позиционирование с отсутствием какого-либо слоя.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Avt extends JPanel{

    Dimension sizeWindow = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Image bg_launch = new ImageIcon("images/style/launch.jpg").getImage();

    JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Login: ");
    JTextField loginText = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(10);

    JButton submit = new JButton("Войти");

    public Avt() {
        setLayout(null);
        loginLabel.setBounds(85, 10, 130, 18);
        loginText.setBounds(160, 10, 120, 20);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(85, 40, 120, 18);
        password.setBounds(160, 40, 120, 20);
        submit.setBounds(160, 70, 80, 30);

        add(loginLabel);
        add(loginText);
        add(passwordLabel);
        add(password);
        add(submit);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(bg_launch != null){
            g.drawImage(bg_launch, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Avt());
        frame.setSize(400, 160);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[Документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

Comment: @horcrux, а что, использование `setBounds()` не приветствуется?

Comment: Я такого не писал =)
Конечно можно все абсолютно задавать, но настоятельно рекомендую разобраться со слоями: они полезны.
В документации вот как, кстати, написано:
"Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible. A layout manager makes it easier to adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to different font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different locales. Layout managers also can be reused easily by other containers, as well as other programs."

Comment: Очень полезно!!! Я кажется целую вечность пыхтел на вопросом, как на JFrame засунуть романтический фон (свою -jpg) - с помощью ImageIcon, JLabel и чтобы потом не шарахались по углам дочерние компоненты, скажем JTextField - с помощью jtf.setBounds(85, 10, 130, 18); 
Четко и там, где нужно!
Ура

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь layout manager'ом. В зависимости от того, какое расположение контролов вам нужно, выберите подходящий.

Вот [документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).